# How to Integrate Authorize.Net ARB and AIM together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-arb

I want to Integrate Authorized.Net ARB and AIM together using rails.

Actually, I want Instant payment when user signs up today and I want the subscription to start today. for this i want to charge their first payment via the AIM API. and if AIM tranaction get succeed then only i will create ARB.I write code for both my ARB works perfect but when i write code for the AIM it gives error `This transaction has been declined` but when i create an ARB with same card it works perfectly.I really don't know how to go for this.

Also I want to know when subscription is declined when processing a future scheduled payment is Authorize.Net cancelled that Subscription or try again on next day?if it try next day again how many times it will try? Can I check or write a code using `SILENT POST` that after 5 times it's subscription should get cancelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARB performs no validation of a credit card when a subscription is created (other then validating the card has a valid card number format, properly formatted expiration date, etc and won't expire before the first payment is scheduled for). Therefore you have to use AIM to validate the card first, either by running a transaction or performing an AUTH_ONLY, and then if it is successful establish the subscription with ARB. Basically once you get that decline from AIM your script should abort and notify the user of the error and have them try again with a new credit card.

If a subscription payment is declined the subscription will be suspended. If you update the subscription before the next scheduled payment is due the missed payment will automatically be attempted again and if successful the subscription will be active again.

<s>There is no way through any current API to check the status of a subscription. It currently can only be done through the control panel. It is on their to do list so this may change in the future.</s>

**UPDATE 2011-12-01**

The ARB API now offers the [`ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest`](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/New-ARB-Call-ARBGetSubscriptionStatus-Available-on-8-24/td-p/4824) call to get a subscription's status.

Comment: @john :- thanx john for this helpfyl information.But somehow my AMI and ARB are not working together what you what is the reason?

Comment: Well, they don't technically work together in a literal sense. You have to use them together in your own way. Use AIM to process the first subscription payment. If it comes up declined then don't even attempt to set up the ARB subscription. If you still try to set up the subscription anyway it will succeed but the first payment will fail which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: @john :- thanks john. Do i need to enable AIM for my merchant account or it already enabled?Or it happens because ARB is not execute in TEST mode and AMI only work in TEST mode? looking forward for your reply....

Comment: AIM is always enabled and ARB never affects AIM. I recommend getting a developer account from Authorize.Net and doing your testing that way. That way you can test everything without test mode and see exactly how it will work.

Comment: @John:- Thanx million it's done. I create a developer account with AIM and ARB Enabled and write it into the code.I think when i use real credit card with real API login ID it will work now.am i correct?